# How to make image with watermark in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, watermark

I want to take photo in my flutter app to avoid inputting fake picture. So, I will make my app to Take photo and Save photo with current DateTime and Longitude, Latitude Watermark. Can anybody show me how can I achieve this?

Comment: pls do not down vote without giving useful information like duplicate question with already successfully answered link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward library would be https://pub.dev/packages/image.

In the [examples](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki/Examples), it shows:

> Create an image, draw some text, save it as a png

```
// Draw some text using 24pt arial font
drawString(image, arial_24, 0, 0, 'Hello World');
```

But there should be plenty of other image editors searched at https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=edit+image